# Unknown CMake command "gtest_discover_tests"

Tags: cmake, compilation, googletest

Can someone explain me please how to install properly Cmake and GoogleTest so the command

```
gtest_discover_tests
```

becomes available ?. I installed

```
cmake-3.23.0-rc3
```

and

```
googletest-release-1.11.0
```

from source but I still can't compile that project

```
https://github.com/D-os/libbinder
```

because of fallowing error

```
CMake Error at tests/CMakeLists.txt:15 (gtest_discover_tests):
Unknown CMake command "gtest_discover_tests".
```

I'm using Slackware 14.2 x64

Comment: What does `cmake --version` show?

Comment: cmake version 3.23.0-rc3

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That function is defined in the [`GoogleTest`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GoogleTest.html) script file (module) so you need to include it like this: `include(GoogleTest)`

Then you can use the function.

Comment: Must be missing something. Even after `include(GoogleTest)` this still would give the same error for me as for @Daro

Comment: @JoergS what is the CMake version you are using?

Comment: I am using 3.24. But I found the issue. Turns out, I have to put the include before adding any custom folder to CMAKE_MODULES. Though I did not expect this.